# I'm having trouble using the Latex web, could you please help me with how to illustrate the formula below? I'm sorry, I'm new to using this website

Tags: chemistry

```
\chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-\lewis{26,O}-H}\quad\quad\quad\quad\chemfig{H-\lewis{26,O}-H}
\chemmove{\draw-,dashed..controls +(90:5mm) and +(90:5mm)..(O2);}
\chemmove{\draw-,dashed..controls +(270:5mm) and +(270:5mm)..(O3);}
\chemmove{\draw-,dashed..controls +(90:5mm) and +(90:5mm)..(O4);}
\chemmove{\draw-,dashed..controls +(270:5mm) and +(270:5mm)..(O5);}
```

Answer (score 1):

the "\lewis" command no longer works in ChemFig, use "\charge", check the chemfig manual. You didn't write the \lewis command correctly

I couldn't understand what you wanted to do with the "\draw" commands. Could you include an image of what your drawing should look like?

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-\charge{90=\:}{O}-H} \hspace{1cm} \chemfig{H-\charge{90=\:}{O}-H}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]